# Leyendo Mongo db con map-reduce Mongo-hadoop

Tags: mongodb, hadoop

Estoy tratando de leer documentos de una base de datos en mongoDB mediante Hadoop mapreduce(python), e imprimir los documentos en un .txt para comprobar que puedo manejarlos.

Para ello me he instalado la libreria mongo-hadoop, la cual viene con 3 ejemplos que se supone son funcionales. El codigo del map (modificado para mi base de datos) es el siguiente:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from pymongo import MongoClient
import bson
from bson.codec_options import CodecOptions
from bson.json_util import loads, dumps
from pymongo_hadoop import BSONMapper

def mapper(documents):
    f.write(str("si imprimo\n"))
    f.write(str(documents))
    for doc in documents:
        f.write(str("no imprimo nada!!!"))
        f.write(str(doc['campo']))
        yield {'_id': doc['_id'], 'campo': doc['campo']}


f=open("/home/miguel/Escritorio/MapReduce_python/dicc", "w")
sys.path.append(".")
BSONMapper(mapper)
```

Los documentos de mongo son los siguientes:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d19cfd9256b0a4686559918"),
    "campo" : "casa"
}
```

Y en el fichero se escribe:

```
si imprimo
<pymongo_hadoop.input.BSONInput object at 0x7f5fa168f490>
```

Por último me da el siguiente error:

```
  File "/home/miguel/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo_hadoop/input.py", line 28, in _read
    doc = BSON(data).decode(tz_aware=True)
TypeError: decode() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tz_aware'
2019-07-17 14:28:28,255 INFO streaming.PipeMapRed: MRErrorThread done
2019-07-17 14:28:28,255 INFO io.BSONWritable: No Length Header available.java.io.EOFException
2019-07-17 14:28:28,256 INFO streaming.PipeMapRed: PipeMapRed failed!
java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:539)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:465)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:349)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:271)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-07-17 14:28:28,259 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map task executor complete.
2019-07-17 14:28:28,260 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local1570689928_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:492)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:552)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:539)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:465)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:349)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:271)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-07-17 14:28:28,742 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1570689928_0001 running in uber mode : false
2019-07-17 14:28:28,745 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
2019-07-17 14:28:28,750 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1570689928_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: NA
2019-07-17 14:28:28,760 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
2019-07-17 14:28:28,760 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Job not successful!
Streaming Command Failed!
```

No se como hacer para conseguir manejar los documentos...gracias.